# How do i redirect on my Server 2012 R2 incoming domain requests?

Tags: domain, redirect, port

I have two virtual machines on my server which use port 80.
How do i redirect 
sub1.home.home to machine 1
and
sub2.home.home to machine 2

I think my router is not capatable for that, so port 80 needs to be handled somehow on the server.

Thanks for hints and help.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIR, you can use 3rd VM with Apache HTTP server with virtual hosts and mod_proxy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223153/redirect-domain-request-to-different-vm-machines

This article https://freedif.org/redirect-a-subdomain-to-a-vm-with-haproxy/ can be helpful too.